# Azure App Service how to programmatically move deploy.cmd

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I'm using app services with git hooks so that my git pushes automatically get sent to the app service. Everything in my repo ends up in the `\site\wwwroot\` directory which is nice. However, I need the `deploy.cmd` file to end up in the deployments `\site\deployments\tools` and I'd like this automated.

The `deploy.cmd` file is read/executed every time I push new code which is really convenient for being able to automatically build new code and have it running on my machine after each push but if I make changes to `deploy.cmd`, I have to push my code, manually (via FTP or console) copy the new deploy.cmd file to the right place, then run the script or re-push my code.

Is there a way to automatically place my new `deploy.cmd` file in the right spot immediately after a push and *then* have it execute automatically?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To use a Kudu custom deployment script, you need both a `.deployment` files and a `deploy.cmd` file (see [wiki](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Custom-Deployment-Script)). Once you have that, your script will always be used, and you should never have to worry about the `\site\deployments\tools` folder. Generally, you are not ever supposed to manually modify this folder.